# JS code injection into console freezes the website

Tags: javascript, code-injection

I have created very simple JS script to automate tasks on specific website (Clicking element when it appears etc..) It has 3 functions in which are 3 while true loops, basically each of those has a infinite loop which is asking if specific element is present on website, and if yes then I click it and call another function which is composed the same way, looking for a element and if it appears, it should click it. So I do have 3 functions Main(), Function2(), Function3() and I start by calling Main(), If element appears in Main() I call function2() then function3 from f2() and from f3() back to Main(), should be an infinite looping, but after I copy paste the code into console the website instantly becomes lagged and I need to restart browser, why does this happen? How do I fix it to be able to run the script correctly? (Iam very new to JS, this might be coded very wrongly)

```
function function3(){
    while (true) {
        let BTN = document.querySelector("....")
        if (BTN != null){
            BTN.click()
            main()
        }
    }
}

function function2(){

    while (true){
        let anotherElementButton = document.querySelector("...")
        if (anotherElementButton != null){
            anotherElementButton.click()
            function3()
        }
    }
}

function main(){

    while (true){
        let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('tag-of-the-elements')
        if (elements.length > 0){
            Array.from(elements).forEach(btn => btn.click())
            function2()
        }
    }
}
main()
```

Comment: I see not one, not two, but three infinite loops. How do you expect it to work?

Comment: Your main function calls function2, which calls function3, which calls main, all of which are calling eachother using infinite loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably happened since each time you create a new instance of main, f2, and f3 and how it is in an infinite loop, the browser lags until it becomes completely unavailable.

If you want to check if an element is on the screen and then execute an action you probably should use something like Mutation observer to observe for changes on DOM or setInterval

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp